# Get Gridview dropdownList value

Tags: asp.net

work on asp.net vs05.I have a grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="StudentID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged" 
OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" ReadOnly="True" 
           SortExpression="StudentID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DivisionName">
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Bind("StudentName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                             Width="160px"></asp:DropDownList>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="Update" 
       Text="Update" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Using The button Click i want to save value on database.But i can not read value from the dropdownlist

```
protected void GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow selectRow = GridView3.SelectedRow;
   String ID = selectRow.Cells[0].Text;
   String Name = selectRow.Cells[1].Text;
   //String Dis = selectRow.Cells[2].Text;

   String Dis = 
           ((DropDownList)sender).FindControl("DropDownList1").ToString();
                   //**want to get this value**
    }
```

**How can i get ddl selected value?i want to put the object of a class on ddl .Bellow code work on desktop ,Want same thing on web.**

```
DropDownList1.DisplayMember = "CommercialRegionName";
foreach (class oItem in _collection)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(oItem);
        //**want to save object,Not any object item like:oItem.Name.**
}
```

Comment: ...and voting up (one +1 was probably accidental)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow selectRow = GridView3.SelectedRow;
   String ID = selectRow.Cells[0].Text;
   String Name = selectRow.Cells[1].Text;
   //String Dis = selectRow.Cells[2].Text;

   //PROBABLY YOU WANT TO GET ITEM FROM SELECTED ROW'S DROPDOWN
   var ddl = (selectRow).FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropdownList;
   if(dis!=null){
        var s=ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
   }
}
```